# Parse the Assistant V1 MessageResponse into JSON

Tags: ios, swift, react-native-ios, ibm-watson

I'm creating a chatbot in react-native using IBM Watson Assistant. Since there was no good library I decided to create a bridge myself.

So the problem i'm facing here is in iOS , I'm able to get the response but i want it to be in json format. I'm using swift 4.

The format I receive:

```
(input: Optional(AssistantV1.MessageInput(text: Stupid)), intents: [], entities: [], alternateIntents: nil, context: AssistantV1.Context(conversationID: Optional("2380129380139312kjh123"), system: Optional(AssistantV1.SystemResponse(additionalProperties: ["_node_output_map": RestKit.JSON.object(["Welcome": RestKit.JSON.object(["1": RestKit.JSON.array([RestKit.JSON.int(0), RestKit.JSON.int(0), RestKit.JSON.int(1), RestKit.JSON.int(2)])])]), "initialized": RestKit.JSON.boolean(true), "branch_exited": RestKit.JSON.boolean(true), "dialog_stack": RestKit.JSON.array([RestKit.JSON.object(["dialog_node": RestKit.JSON.string("root")])]), "dialog_turn_counter": RestKit.JSON.int(1), "dialog_request_counter": RestKit.JSON.int(1), "branch_exited_reason": RestKit.JSON.string("completed")])), additionalProperties: ["error_question": RestKit.JSON.string(""), "my_name": RestKit.JSON.string("username"), "my_email": RestKit.JSON.string("useremail"), "my_credentials": RestKit.JSON.object(["password": RestKit.JSON.string("3120834hbdi37dyd"), "user": RestKit.JSON.string("uwq9383ueh9833298e")]), "err_cnt": RestKit.JSON.int(0)]), output: AssistantV1.OutputData(logMessages: [], text: ["Sorry, I am constantly learning."], generic: Optional([AssistantV1.DialogRuntimeResponseGeneric(responseType: "image", text: nil, time: nil, typing: nil, source: Optional("someurl"), title: nil, description: nil, preference: nil, options: nil, messageToHumanAgent: nil, topic: nil, suggestions: nil), AssistantV1.DialogRuntimeResponseGeneric(responseType: "text", text: Optional("Sorry, I am constantly learning."), time: nil, typing: nil, source: nil, title: nil, description: nil, preference: nil, options: nil, messageToHumanAgent: nil, topic: nil, suggestions: nil)]), nodesVisited: Optional(["Welcome"]), nodesVisitedDetails: nil, additionalProperties: [:]), actions: nil, additionalProperties: [:])
```

The format I want:

```
{"entities":[],"output":{"generic":[{"source":"someurl","response_type":"image"},{"response_type":"text","text":"Sorry, I am constantly learning."}],"text":["Sorry, I am constantly learning."],"nodes_visited":["node_1_1535596064008"],"log_messages":[]},"intents":[{"intent":"Negative_Feedback","confidence":1}],"context":{"system":{"dialog_turn_counter":3,"initialized":true,"dialog_stack":[{"dialog_node":"root"}],"dialog_request_counter":3,"_node_output_map":{"node_2_1536025247756":{"0":[0]},"Welcome":{"1":[0,0,1,2]},"node_1_1535596064008":{"1":[0,0]}},"branch_exited":true,"branch_exited_reason":"completed"},"my_name":"username","err_cnt":0,"conversation_id":"13212230293","error_question":"","my_email":"useremail","my_credentials":{"user":"123192312b3283y12b129","password":"dadu8sdsadjb283"}},"input":{"text":"Stupid"}}
```

Comment: You mentioned that you couldn't find a good library that bridged IBM Watson to react-native. Have you tried [this library](https://github.com/pwcremin/react-native-watson)? It hasn't been maintained in awhile, but might be worth a shot (or at least a fork to get it working).

Comment: The version used in this library is old. I have used it for the android part, but the iOS build fails.

Comment: That's a shame. I edited my answer below to show you a workaround that will allow you to convert response objects to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift SDK will support 2-way conversion between objects and raw JSON once version 1.0 is released (by the end of this year). Here is the PR that will implement the functionality to support changing response objects back into JSON: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/pull/910.

If you cannot wait for version 1.0 to be released (which will likely be at the end of the year), then you can clone the swift-sdk repo and reproduce the PR I linked above for the models you are using (basically changing the type from `Decodable` to `Codable`). For your `MessageResponse` example, you would make [these changes](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/pull/910/files#diff-dd1571f4dc94928c94a370aacace18e5). Then, in your request completion handler, do something like this:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(messageResponse)
    if let rawJSON = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(rawJSON)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I was stuck with this from last two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Watson's Swift SDK? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk. You can see the example of using Assistant using Watson swift SDK here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/tree/master/Source/AssistantV1.

Comment: the response I've shared above is from the watsons swift sdk.